# Sample google-analytics report

Tags: google-analytics

I am doing a project which is related to tracking websites response in different mobile browsers. For this It required  sample  google analytics report which gives the details of **Traffic** that is coming from different  **mobile browsers/Tablets**. Can anyone please provide sample google analytics report which contains how much traffic is coming from *safari/chrome/android* etc....  mobilebrowsers.

or else please suggest any URL where i can get these statistics

Comment: Couldn't you use the Audience > Mobile > Devices report?

Comment: I wish could.But I don't have website with google analytics configured. is there any open source kind of thing for this to get @Blexy.